# How can someone answer my survey form or Google form without creating their own Google account?

Tags: google-forms

How can someone answer my survey form or Google form without creating their own Google account? They told me that they can't open my form because they didn't have an account.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Normally, everyone can fill out a Google form; they do not need an account.

However, if you selected the option "Can submit only 1 response" in your Google form, that will require the users to login. So, if it's necessary to allow anonymous users, you should uncheck that option.

Also, it's a good idea to *test* the form yourself, by using a browser session in which you are not logged in to Google. You can do this using a private/incognito window of your browser (for example, in Chrome pressing Ctrl-Shift-N opens such a window). It's highly recommended to test your form in this way before sending out the link.

Comment: Additionally, there are questions you can not ask for the public to answer: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/1868273?hl=en&msgid=1868390. Certain inputs, such as file uploads, requires a login (apparently). I've complained about this multiple times but nothing seems to change.

Answer (score 14):

In my case even after disabling 'Limit to 1 Response' I was not able to access the form publically and it was asking users to login. Later I found that I had chosen 'File Upload' from few questions in that form, which were forcing my users to login to access the form. I deleted those 'File Upload' question from the form and then my users were able to access the form without login.

Comment: That was my issue. I however need to have the file upload. Does anyone know of a different tool that could do the job?

Answer (score 5):

If your form includes *File upload* widget, this will trigger the sign in requirement as well, likely because it utilizes Google Drive (and thus requires a Google account).

Comment: It utilizes Google Drive of the owner, not of the one that is uploading right?

Comment: Yes, but the login is required

Answer (score 3):

The default settings on a form from Google Forms could vary depending on if you are using a consumer/free account or a G Suite / paid / education / not for profit account

If the form creator is using a consumer account, usually with a gmail.com email address as username, the default setting doesn't require to sign in into a any account.

By the other hand, if the form creator is using a G Suite account, the default setting is to require users to sign in into a "domain" account in order to be able to respond.

It's worth to note that at this time there are two settings that could require a user to sign-in in order to be able to respond:

1. Limit to one answer by user
2. Require login into a "domain account"

References

- [Send your form to people](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2839588?hl=en).
- [Can't open a form](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/160166?hl=en).

Answer (score 3):

For me following steps solved the same problem:

In your created Google Form:

- Go to the icon at top left, the one with tree bullets
- then click add collaborators
- Who has access
- change to On - Public or On - Anyone

Answer (score 1):

- Go to the icon at top left, the one with tree bullets
- then click add collaborators
- Who has access
- change to On - Public or On - Anyone